# naming convention for concurring C and C++ libraries (alternatives to yaml.h vs yaml.h?)

Tags: c++, c, include, naming-conventions, libraries

To write a YAML loader or exporter under C++, there are two different approaches:

- use the C library `libyaml`, therefore include `yaml.h`;
- use the C++ library `libyaml-cpp`, therefore include `yaml-cpp/yaml.h`.

The use of the same file name `yaml.h` for two different APIs is a possible source of confusion and error. How could the developers of `libyaml-cpp` have done better:

Are there counterexamples of concurring C and C++ libraries that have chosen different names for their include files?

Are there any generic recommendations how to handle such cases?

Comment: `yaml.h` and `yaml.hpp`? It's clear and simple distinction.

Comment: yeah ... but this question is not about suggestions and opinions (otherwise the police force would close it), but about precedents and links to published advice.

Comment: [GTK+](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GTK%2B) vs. [gtkmm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gtkmm). I don't believe that there were exactly equal named headers. The gtkmm API is partly auto-generated. However, it introduced a `namespace GTK` and stripped "class" names from function identifiers when turning them into methods.

Comment: There are only a few short names and many programmers; you'll always have conflicts. Even the implied assumption that there is exactly one C implementation of YAML is weak.